# How to run bash command in Boto3 EMR initialization

Tags: bash, pyspark

To avoid putting connection strings in an S3 bash script, I would like to add an inline bash command in my initialize script that would add environmental variables to the .bash_profile. That way, my pyspark application could use hit the bash_profile instead of inline connection strings.   I would like to add something like the following to the EMR Boto3 init script.  Does anyone know how to do this? OR know a better way to keep connection strings out of your pyspark code?

```
BootstrapActions=[
            {
                'Name': 'Download_MYSQL_JDBC',
                'ScriptBootstrapAction':{
                    'Command':'export mysql_password="password!" >>~/.bash_profile'
                    }
                }
]
```

Comment: `export` does not print anything to standard output, so this will not actually write anything to the file. Did you mean to add the `export` command itself to the file?

Comment: I would like to just execute a command. No file. Unless you know a way to use a file that would be secure.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'export mysql_password="password!"' >>~/.bash_profile` would add the command to the startup file; but the proper solution is to use an actual secrets manager.

Comment: I never thought about using like KMS. That would be better?